# Are any of these metrics equivalent?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I have the space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$, $C([0,1]),$ with 3 different metrics, $d_1, d_2$ and $d_{\infty}$. Where $d_1(f,g)=\int_{0}^1|f(t)-g(t)|dt$, $d_2(f,g)=(\int_{0}^1|f(t)-g(t)|^{2})^{0.5}dt$ and $d_{\infty}=sup_{t\in[0,1]}(|f(t)-g(t)|)$ I am asked to show if anyof them are equivalent, I know the meaning of this but have no clue where to start, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: To show a pair aren't equivalent, you in effect need to find a bounded sequence of functions in one of the metrics, which is unbounded in the other.

Comment: Are you sure the exponent $\frac 12$ is inside the integral for $d_2$? Otherwise $d_1 = d_2$.

Comment: The exponent isnt inside the integral. And so I need to find a sequence $f_n$ s.t. $d_i(f,0)$ is bounded and $d_j(f,0)$ isnt?

Comment: You’ll need the definition of “equivalent” that is in the mind of the person asking the question. Can you add that to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints:
Easy inequalities to prove are the following:
$$
d_2(f,g) \leq d_\infty d(f,g) \\
d_1(f,g) \leq d_\infty d(f,g) \\
d_1(f,g) \leq d_2(f,g).
$$
To prove the last one you'll need the Hölder's inequality. As a last hint, none of the metrics are actually equivalent. So you should be able to find sequence of functions that are convergent in $d_i$, but not in $d_\infty$ for $i=1,2$ and a sequence of functions that is convergent in $d_1$ but not in $d_2$. These aren't too hard to find, consider for example a sequence with $f_n(0)=1$ for all $n$ but for which the integral converges to zero.